# Windows 8 doesn't shut down

Tags: windows-8, troubleshooting, shutdown, reboot

I have Windows 8 Pro 64 bit and everything worked fine for 2 months, but now suddenly my PC doesn't want to shut down. I've tried restart, but nothing happens. When I log off and try to restart/shut down, nothing happens, just a gray screen shows. I've closed all programs and processes (except some Windows processes that you can't end), I've also updated Windows, but nothing happens.

If I start up my PC and I get the login screen and I press restart, it works (before logging in), but shut down doesn't, it just shows a gray screen.

There are a lot of posts on this problem for Win7, and a lot of the answers say to hard shut down it (by pressing the power button). I however use a SSD (Crucial M4) and there is an "official" known problem that if you don't properly shut down your pc (eg hard reset), BIOS won't detect the drive. You then need to open the BIOS setup menu and wait for 30min to reset your drive. So I don't want to wait 30min every time I stat-up, so hard shut down is not an option.

I just installed Win8 two months ago, I don't want to format again. Any suggestions on this problem?

Comment: Check the event viewer for any errors or warnings.

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl-Alt-Del when the system is hung like that, to see if you can get Task Manager up?  If so you can at least look at what's running and maybe hanging things up.

Comment: What action is Windows set to use as "Shutdown"?  Hibernation? Hybrid sleep? a real shut down?  Are there any peripherals plugged in (printers, scanners, etc.)?

Comment: All actions are set to "Shut Down".

Comment: And my PC doesn't hang. If I press shut down, nothing happens. I can continue with the work, but the PC never shuts down.

Comment: I have the same issue for the last 3 days. I use Power off button to switch off, and I know its not the right way to do.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [Windows 8 System Restore](http://www.vikitech.com/11302/system-restore-windows-8) feature to roll your system back to an earlier date when it still worked.

Comment: Did that just now. Still can't shut down.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also.  Windows 8 was fine.  Then I could no longer shut down, sign out or restart.  However sleep worked and hibernate worked. If I held down the power button to hard switch off it would just start up again by its self a few seconds later.

I have an Crucial SSD in my computer.  The Mobo is MSI.  Proc I5 with intel chipset.

I went into my BIOS and change the hard drive mode from IDE to RAID which will also be AHCI. (I guess AHCI would also work its just another article said its best to chose RAID so you have it if needed.)  Then I re-installed windows.  (had to re-install once I changed the mode.)  Now windows 8 works fine.  Not sure if you problem is similar.